# hosting multiple apps under single google account in GAE

Tags: google-app-engine

is it possible to host multiple apps in GAE using single google account.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can host as many as ten application on GAE for a single account for free. Each application can have n number of serving version provided they don't go beyond free usage quota. To know more about free usage quota in GAE. You can have a look [here](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/quotas.html)

Answer (score 2):

As far as I remember you can have max 10 projects per account in your appengine. The trick is you can configure your applications to communicate with each other and exchange data through some REST integration they way most web services work either xml or json are solid solutions for the proble. Send more specific inquiries if you have.